# Longer delay before scrollbar disappears

Tags: macos

I would like to use one of the first two options on the `Show scroll bars` controls:

[image]

The problem is that the scrollbar disappears like almost immediately and I can not get the cursor on top of it soon enough.  It is presently about one second of visibility: even just *two* seconds would be sufficient.

Is there any way to make this behavior more usable - short of using the big hammer and setting to `Always` ?

Comment: Can you try the 1st option? Based on mouse?

Comment: That was my original selection